# Having system-wide crashes on MacBook with OS X 10.10.1 using Screenflow 5.0

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

I'm having system-wide random crashes when trying to record computer screen and audio using Screenflow 5.0

Computer
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
2.4 GHz Intel Core i5 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 Intel Iris 1536 MB
OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)

I did the online Apple Hardware Test and everything looks ok.
Any leads?

Here's a crash log:

```
Anonymous UUID:       E47FE6B0-9479-A72A-C505-9E4A39BF5EE5

Mon Jan 12 20:06:55 2015

*** Panic Report ***
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c07
family: 6 model: 69 stepping: 1 microcode: 23
signature: 0x40651
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4258U CPU @ 2.40GHz
7 error-reporting banks
Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
IA32_MC6_STATUS(0x419): 0xbe0000000008111a
IA32_MC6_ADDR(0x41a):   0x00000000feb80080
IA32_MC6_MISC(0x41b):   0x0000007042000086
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
IA32_MC6_STATUS(0x419): 0xbe0000000008111a
IA32_MC6_ADDR(0x41a):   0x00000000feb80080
IA32_MC6_MISC(0x41b):   0x0000007042000086
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
IA32_MC6_STATUS(0x419): 0xbe0000000008111a
IA32_MC6_ADDR(0x41a):   0x00000000feb80080
IA32_MC6_MISC(0x41b):   0x0000007042000086
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
IA32_MC6_STATUS(0x419): 0xbe0000000008111a
IA32_MC6_ADDR(0x41a):   0x00000000feb80080
IA32_MC6_MISC(0x41b):   0x0000007042000086
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800da1f12a): "Machine Check at 0xffffff800da3af57, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000114a50498, CR3: 0x0000000010626000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000060, RBX: 0x07fffffffffffb5f, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff8119183ee0, RBP: 0xffffff8119183f20, RSI: 0xffffff800e0e8c40, RDI: 0xffffff800e029d60\n" "R8:  0x0000000100000000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000001, R11: 0x0000000000000200\n" "R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff800e0e8fc0, R14: 0x0000000000000340, R15: 0x0000000000000060\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP: 0xffffff800da3af57, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:1 68
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810f75de90 : 0xffffff800d93a811
0xffffff810f75df10 : 0xffffff800da1f12a
0xffffff810f75e070 : 0xffffff800da3acef
0xffffff8119183f20 : 0xffffff800da202ae
0xffffff8119183f40 : 0xffffff800d9514bb
0xffffff8119183f90 : 0xffffff800d951970
0xffffff8119183fb0 : 0xffffff800da192c7

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14B25

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x000000000d600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800d800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800d700000
System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 625247613175
last loaded kext at 21430535164: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch 85.3 (addr 0xffffff7f8fddb000, size 61440)
last unloaded kext at 113064189506: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C 2.0.45 (addr 0xffffff7f8f871000, size 36864)
loaded kexts:
net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio 1.1.1
com.karios.driver.DuetDisplay 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch 85.3
com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.1.0d1
com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.14.37
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 267.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface 5.23.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 2.0.4d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess 1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV 1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul 10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.2.10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub 705.4.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360 901.19.10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 161
com.apple.security.quarantine 3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver 4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver 260.30
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 267.0
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 267.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 97
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.4.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 156.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite 705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage 471
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter 4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily 4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI 3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 700.52
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox 300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread 1
com.apple.kec.Libm 1
Model: MacBookPro11,1, BootROM MBP111.0138.B11, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.16f68
Graphics: Intel Iris, Intel Iris, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384B54463531323634485A2D314736453120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384B54463531323634485A2D314736453120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x112), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.10)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.1f2 15015, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.2

MacBook Pro with Retina display, OS X Yosemite (10.10.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [DuetDisplay](http://www.duetdisplay.com/faq) is not supported by 10.10

```
com.karios.driver.DuetDisplay 1
```

> Does it support 10.10.2 beta?
>
> Not at this time. The OS X build itself is very unstable and is
>   causing issues with duet. We are in touch with Apple and asking them
>   to fix the issues so that duet works optimally.

Also not sure your update for [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/telestream-support/screen-flow/faq.htm)5 app is working.

```
net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio 1.1.1
```

> Version 4.5.4 Fixes and Improvements
>
> Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite compatibility
>
> Fixed graphics problem error when applying video filters
>
> Fixed issue in 10.10 where a black canvas would result when playing
>   back imported video files
>
> Fixed crash occurring when trying to export a preset with a special
>   character in
>   10.10